# What is the result of $2^{3^4}$?

Tags: notation, arithmetic

Simple question: what does $2^{3^4}$ equal to? I am asking this because some calculators take this as $2^{(3^4)}$ and others as ${(2^3)}^4$.

Comment: @Martin R: You're right. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an explicit example or two of calculators that do the evaluation each way?

Comment: I reverted the edit because the notation 2^3^4 to me is quite different from $2^{3^4}$ which almost unambiguously means 2^(3^4),not sure what the OP means.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no "correct" answer per se. Because $(2^3)^4 \neq 2^{(3^4)}$, you should really specify which one you mean to avoid confusion. However, we most often decide that exponentiation associates to the right -- that is, $2^{3^4}$ is taken to mean $2^{(3^4)}$ -- because $(2^3)^4$ can also less confusingly be written as $2^{3 \cdot 4} = 2^{12}$.

Comment: But I learned that $x^{y^z}$ was $x^{(y^z)}$ ...

Comment: @jeff, to avoid confusion, teachers will often say that $x^{y^z}$ *is* $x^{(y^z)}$, just like they will often say that $a + b \cdot c$ *is* $a + (b \cdot c)$. There is no deep truth to these facts. We could more or less just as well have decided that $a + b \cdot c$ means $(a + b) \cdot c$. It is just notation. The important thing is that you communicate in such a way that the reader understands what you mean. To avoid having to write parentheses all the time, we have conventions. The convention $a + b \cdot c = a + (b \cdot c)$ is very strong; that $x^{y^z} = x^{(y^z)}$ is weaker.

Comment: processing this through my head right now....

Answer (score 4):

If you write $a^{b^c}$ then most people take that as $a^{(b^c)}.$  If you write a^b^c, then almost everyone will stop and ask you where your parens are.  Even Maple refuses to do the calculation without parens.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $$2^{3^4}$$ $$=2^{81}$$ Which means the order is from top to bottom i.e. $2^{(3^4)}$